# Any Way of Waiting for Console Unfocus or Pause Until Not Focused?

Tags: c++, console, focus

I have a simple problem that I am struggling to find an answer to. In my situation, I am attempting to wait for user input into the console to activate the main loop of the program, but the program can not be allowed to enter the main loop until the window behind it is in focus. If you do not understand what I mean, here is an example. I have two windows, the one in focus(on top) is the console running the program which is at a pause state while waiting for the window behind it to become the window on top and in focus. I think that either enabling the console to read keyboard input while not in focus or having the program recognize that it is no longer in focus would work. Is it possible to pull off either of those situations in Windows?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think "focus" doesn't mean what you think it means. "Pause state" on the other hand has no special meaning. If your program has a "pause state", then you defined that state, and you define when the state is entered. So just enter the pause state when you feel like it.

That said, the strict answer to your question is the [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx) message, but that arrives in the message loop for a window and you don't own the message loop of a console window.